# Vagrant, error in vagrant up --provider=vmware_workstation. VMware version mismatch

Tags: windows, vagrant

I wanted to `vagrant up --provider=vmware_workstation`. However, an error has occurred.

```
$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.8.7

$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-vmware-workstation
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-vmware-workstation (4.0.14)'!

$ vagrant plugin license vagrant-vmware-workstation C:/license.lic
Installing license for 'vagrant-vmware-workstation'...
The license for 'vagrant-vmware-workstation' was successfully installed!

$ vagrant up --provider=vmware_workstation
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'vmware_workstation' provider...
This provider only works with VMware Workstation 9.x, 10.x, 11.x, and
12.x. You have Workstation ''. Please install the proper
version of VMware Workstation and try again.
```

I used this Vagrantfile:

```
# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "vmware_precise64"
  config.vm.provider "vmware_workstation" do |v|
    v.gui = true
   end
end
```

I use this version of VMware:

[image: I used VMware is this.]

## List of the things that I've tried.

- Reinstall Vagrant.
- Reinstall VMware.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have VMware Workstation (Pro) installed and Vagrant reports the error.

You are using the free VMware Workstation Player which is [not supported](https://www.vagrantup.com/vmware/):

> CAN I USE VMWARE WORKSTATION PLAYER?
>
> Some features of the Vagrant VMware Workstation plugin will work with VMware Player, but it is not officially supported. Vagrant interacts with VMware via the VMware API, and some versions of VMware Workstation Player do not support those APIs. When in doubt, please purchase VMware Workstation Pro to use all the features supported by the integration.